# .htaccess not working to hide folders in urls

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to remove these two folders: 'folder1s' and 'folder2' from my site's url, and the php extension but it's not taking effect with my .htaccess file.

http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/are_string_beans_all_right_on_the_candida_diet.php

convert

http://www.example.com/are-string-beans-all-right-on-the-candida-diet/

here is my .htaccess file

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ / [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!folder1/folder2).*)$ folder1/folder2/$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do can be easily done if you use RewriteCond

```
# Doesn't begin with folder1/folder2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder1/folder2/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder1/folder2/$1 [L]
```

This will however not redirect a request `http://domain.com/folder1/folder2/file` to `http://domain.com/file`. You'll need a seperate rule for that.

Comment: it's giving error. I want to just hide those two folders and redirect to http://domain.com/file against http://domain.com/folder1/folder2/file

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using url routing functionality.

```
$route['are-string-beans-all-right-on-the-candida-diet'] = "folder1/folder2/are_string_beans_all_right_on_the_candida_diet.php";
```